# Searching Node Modules for javascript files containing the with statement?

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu, sed, visual-studio-code

I have a module that imports a lot of dependencies, which in turn import a lot of dependencies, etc.

When I attempt to use this module in Angular it complains that some of the code contains the deprecated if statement:

```
:Uncaught SyntaxError: Strict mode code may not include a with statement
```

Is there a way to search through all the node modules in VSCode or using a linux command line utility like `sed` or `find` or to find all the files with the with statement in them.  The syntax looks like this:

```
with (object)
    statement
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in `VSCode` go into `User settings` and type `search.exc` and remove `**/node_modules` from patterns and uncheck `Search: Use Ignore Files`